# Creating dynamic styles and binding to UI MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am developing an application in UWP for several months now. I have an issue where I am struggling with creating the styles for the UI components. So far I am making an API call where I get json response with a list of colors (code below). Then I have in my BaseViewModel a Theme object which is set after the api call finishes. I am also using data binding to bind the Theme object to the xaml so the colors can be displayed.
According to an article I read styles are created in the App.xaml as explained here : [UWP - Dynamically load different Styles.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251462/uwp-dynamically-load-different-styles-xaml). and this is where my issue comes I would like to create those styles based on the data I receive in the ThemeModel(code below).

```
 <TextBlock
 x:Name="Count"
  FontSize="10"
 Foreground="{x:BindViewModel.Theme.DefaultColor,Converter={StaticResource   HexStringToSolidBrushConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"         
  Text="{x:Bind SymbolCount ,Mode=TwoWay}"
  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

```
 public class ThemeModel
 {
    public string DefaultColor { get; set; } 

    public string DefaultActionColor { get; set; }

    public string DefaultTextColor { get; set; } 

    public string DefaultTextDarkColor { get; set; }

    public string DefaultTextLightColor { get; set; }

    public string PrimaryColor { get; set; }

    public string PrimaryDarkestColor { get; set; }

    public string PrimaryDarkerColor { get; set; }

    public string PrimaryLighterColor { get; set; }

    public string PrimaryLightestColor { get; set; } 

    public string PrimaryActionColor { get; set; } 

    public string PrimaryTextColor { get; set; }

    public string PrimaryTextLightColor { get; set; }

    public string SecondaryColor { get; set; } 

    public string SecondaryDarkestColor { get; set; } 

    public string SecondaryDarkerColor { get; set; }

    public string SecondaryLightestColor { get; set; }

    public string SecondaryLighterColor { get; set; }

    public string SecondaryActionColor { get; set; }

    public string SecondaryTextColor { get; set; }

    public string SecondaryTextLightColor { get; set; }

    public string HueRedColor { get; set; }

    public string HueRedTextColor { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Maybe a forgotten white space? `x:Bind ViewModel.Theme.DefaultColor`

Comment: You directly bind `Foreground` to a property was good. It's enough to achieve your target. Creating style in code is not correct direction. `Using the Style class in code (for example calling a constructor and building up the Setter values one by one) is very rare. Styles are used for templates, and templates should be available at XAML load time, so any Style created in code is usually available too late to be applied to controls in a UI.`